# Move listbox up and down in MVC /razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I use mvc4/razor, in VS 2012
I'm trying to move the items inside mvc listbox up and down using up and down buttons .
These are my controls inside listorder/index.cshtml
I tried the script ,but this is not working here. please help

```
     @{
         var Resource = new List<SelectListItem> { 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "res1", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "res2", Value = "2" },
         new SelectListItem { Text = "res3", Value = "3" },
          new SelectListItem { Text = "res4", Value = "4" }
    };
}

@Html.ListBox("ListReorder", Resource, new { @class = "ListMain"})
<input type="button" value="Up"  id="ResUpButton" onclick="MoveUp()" /> <br /> 
         <input type="button" value="Down" id="ResDownButton" onclick="MoveDown()" />  



<script src="scripts/jquery-1[1].3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function MoveDown() {
             var selectedOption = $('#ListReorder > option[selected]');
             var nextOption = $('#ListReorder > option[selected]').next("option");
             if ($(nextOption).text() != "") {             
                 $(selectedOption).remove();
                 $(nextOption).after($(selectedOption));
             }                
         }
         function MoveUp() {
             var selectedOption = $('#ListReorder > option[selected]');
             var prevOption = $('#ListReorder > option[selected]').prev("option");
             if ($(prevOption).text() != "") {
                 $(selectedOption).remove();
                 $(prevOption).before($(selectedOption));
             }
           }

    </script>
```

Comment: What's your problem? This works perfectly for me. Where are your up and down buttons?

Comment: I added the code now.My problem is 
when I click the button, the selected listbox item is not showing any action.

Comment: I copied your code into my test project, and it worked. Do you get any error messages? Is your reference to jquery correct?

Comment: @ataravati I placed jquery-1.3.2.js, it not working because of that,?

Comment: I don't know. You are not doing anything super fancy here. But, you can try with a newer version of jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [For more info this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108640/moving-items-between-list-box-using-jquery) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902452/move-and-remove-listbox-item-to-another-listbox-using-jquery)

```
$("#ResUpButton,#ResDownButton").live('click',function(event) {.....
```